# Do browsers still send cookies if I choose to visit an unsafe site warned by browsers?

Tags: web-browser

For example, assume I get a `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` warning in Chrome, when visiting a website. If I still choose to visit that site, do cookies still get sent as usual (when the site is safe, no warning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... visit an unsafe site warned by browsers?

First, these HTTPS related warnings are NOT about the site being safe or not. HTTPS says nothing about the actually security or safety of a site but only cares about protecting the communication between the browser and the site.

These warnings inform you that the communication MIGHT not be properly protected since the certificate does not match the expectations. You should only bypass the warning if you are sure that the site is just wrongly configured, i.e. that the certificate might not match the browsers expectation but it matches your expectation.

Based on this the browser will then assume that the communication is properly protected since the certificate matches what the user expected and will then proceed as normal, including exchanging cookies with this site.